# Get element position after transform

Tags: c#, silverlight, position, transform

I have a UIElement that has various transformations performed on it (scale and translate).

Is there a way to get the UIElement's position after transformation? I tried `GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty)` but it doesn't change from what it was loaded as.

I must be missing something obvious but not sure what. (I'm using silverlight)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is a little bit unintuitive to do this, but it can be done.  It is a two step process.  First, what you want to use the `TransformToVisual` function ([from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.transformtovisual%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)):

> Returns a transform object that can be used to transform coordinates from the UIElement to the specified object.

`TransformToVisual` will yield a `GeneralTransform` that will perform the transformation from any UIElement to any other UIElement (given that they both exist in the same visual tree).  It sounds like what you want is the transformation from the `RootVisual`.

```
var transform = Application.RootVisual.TransformToVisual(myUiElement);
```

The `transform` object is now a general transformation that can be used to transform anything in the same way that `myUiElement` was transformed relative to `RootVisual`

The next step is to transform a point using that transformation.

```
var myUiElementPosition = transform.Transform(new Point(0,0));
```

The `myUiElementPosition` is now a `Point` that has been transformed and should be the position of the `UIElement` you're looking for.  `new Point(0,0)` is used because I assume you want to have the position given relative to the top left corner of the `RootVisual`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this approach:

```
var offset = Application.RootVisual.TransformToVisual(myObject)
                                   .Transform(new Point(0,0));
```

[TransformToVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.transformtovisual%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

ok how about this ?

```
myObjectTransform.GetValue(CompositeTransform.TranslateXProperty)
```

and

```
myObjectTransform.GetValue(CompositeTransform.TranslateYProperty)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this. At the moment, I'm using myObjectTransform.TranslateX += 2. This moves the object across by 2 each frame. Where would I use the GeneralTransform method? thanks

Comment: @Skoder I misunderstood your setup. can you try the edited snippet?

Comment: I get the correct value, but the value isn't the same as the element's position. The value is only relative to the transform, not to the object's position. So the transform's position value is updated, but I need the element's position value.