# Find Polygon Coordinates WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, rotation, coordinates, polygon, transformation

After doing rotating and translating using CompositeTransform. The coordinates for the shapes remain the same in both messagebox.

```
Messagebox.Show(Convert.ToString(T1Shape.Points[i].X)) ;

initialAngle = transform.Rotation;
initialScale = transform.ScaleX; 
transform.TranslateY = -150;
transform.TranslateX = 200;

Messagebox.Show(Convert.ToString(T1Shape.Points[i].X)) ;
```

How do i find out the coordinates of the polygon on the canvas or after transformation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Read this...

[Get element position after transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266506/get-element-position-after-transform)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to apply the transforms by yourself to find out the coordinates after transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You simply get the position of the UIElement relative to `0,0` (assuming you want the standard positions). The translation position is only relative to itself and won't bring back the new position of the polygon itself. Therefore, this should do it:

```
var gtransform = myPolygon.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);
Point position = gtransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

You can then use `position.X` and `position.Y` to get the X and Y positions respectively.