# KinectJS: Algorithm required to determine new X,Y coords after image resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, html, math

**BACKGROUND:**

The app allows users to upload a photo of themselves and then place a pair of glasses over their face to see what it looks like. For the most part, it is working fine. After the user selects the location of the 2 pupils, I auto zoom the image based on the ratio between the distance of the pupils and then already known distance between the center points of the glasses. All is working fine there, but now I need to automatically place the glasses image over the eyes.

I am using KinectJS, but the problem is not with regards to that library or javascript.. it is more of an algorithm requirement

**WHAT I HAVE TO WORK WITH:**

1. Distance between pupils (eyes)
2. Distance between pupils (glasses)
3. Glasses width
4. Glasses height
5. Zoom ratio

**SOME CODE:**

```
//.. code before here just zooms the image, etc..

//problem is here (this is wrong, but I need to know what is the right way to calculate this)
var newLeftEyeX = self.leftEyePosition.x * ratio;
var newLeftEyeY = self.leftEyePosition.y * ratio;

//create a blue dot for testing (remove later)
var newEyePosition = new Kinetic.Circle({
    radius: 3,
    fill: "blue",
    stroke: "blue",
    strokeWidth: 0,
    x: newLeftEyeX,
    y: newLeftEyeY
});
self.pointsLayer.add(newEyePosition);

var glassesWidth = glassesImage.getWidth();
var glassesHeight = glassesImage.getHeight();

// this code below works perfect, as I can see the glasses center over the blue dot created above
newGlassesPosition.x = newLeftEyeX - (glassesWidth / 4);
newGlassesPosition.y = newLeftEyeY - (glassesHeight / 2);
```

**NEEDED**

A math genius to give me the algorithm to determine where the new left eye position should be AFTER the image has been resized

**UPDATE**

After researching this for the past 6 hours or so, I think I need to do some sort of "translate transform", but the examples I see only allow setting this by x and y amounts.. whereas I will only know the scale of the underlying image. Here's the example I found (which cannot help me):

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/transformation.html

and here is something which looks interesting, but it is for Silverlight:

[Get element position after transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266506/get-element-position-after-transform)

Is there perhaps some way to do the same in Html5 and/or KinectJS? Or perhaps I am going down the wrong road here... any ideas people?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried this:

```
// if zoomFactor > 1, then picture got bigger, so...
if (zoomFactor > 1) {
    // if x = 10 (for example) and if zoomFactor = 2, that means new x should be 5
    // current x / zoomFactor => 10 / 2 = 5
    newLeftEyeX = self.leftEyePosition.x / zoomFactor;
    // same for y
    newLeftEyeY = self.leftEyePosition.y / zoomFactor;
}
else {
    // else picture got smaller, so...
    // if x = 10 (for example) and if zoomFactor = 0.5, that means new x should be 20
    // current x * (1 / zoomFactor) => 10 * (1 / 0.5) = 10 * 2 = 20
    newLeftEyeX = self.leftEyePosition.x * (1 / zoomFactor);
    // same for y
    newLeftEyeY = self.leftEyePosition.y * (1 / zoomFactor);
}
```

that didn't work, so then I tried an implementation of Rody Oldenhuis' suggestion (thanks Rody):

```
var xFromCenter = self.leftEyePosition.x - self.xCenter;
var yFromCenter = self.leftEyePosition.y - self.yCenter;

var angle = Math.atan2(yFromCenter, xFromCenter);
var length = Math.hypotenuse(xFromCenter, yFromCenter);

var xNew = zoomFactor * length * Math.cos(angle);
var yNew = zoomFactor * length * Math.sin(angle);

newLeftEyeX = xNew + self.xCenter;
newLeftEyeY = yNew + self.yCenter;
```

However, that is still not working as expected. So, I am not sure what the issue is currently. If anyone has worked with KinectJS before and has an idea of what the issue may be, please let me know.

**UPDATE 3**

I checked Rody's calculations on paper and they seem fine, so there is obviously something else here messing things up.. I got the coordinates of the left pupil at zoom factors 1 and 2. With those coordinates, maybe someone can figure out what the issue is:

Zoom Factor 1: x = 239, y = 209

Zoom Factor 2: x = 201, y = 133

Comment: got lost after u said something about the human eye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, since it's an algorithmic question, I'm going to keep this generic and only write pseudo code.

I f I understand you correctly, What you want is the following:

1. Transform all coordinates such that the origin of your coordinate system is at the zoom center (usually, central pixel)
2. Compute the angle a line drawn from this new origin to a point of interest makes with the positive x-axis. Compute also the length of this line.
3. The new x and y coordinates after zooming are defined by elongating this line, such that the new line is the zoom factor times the length of the original line.
4. Transform the newly found x and y coordinates back to a coordinate system that makes sense to the computer (e.g., top left pixel = 0,0)
5. Repeat for all points of interest.

In pseudo-code (with formulas):

```
x_center = image_width/2
y_center = image_height/2

x_from_zoom_center = x_from_topleft - x_center
y_from_zoom_center = y_from_topleft - y_center

angle  = atan2(y_from_zoom_center, x_from_zoom_center)
length = hypot(x_from_zoom_center, y_from_zoom_center)

x_new = zoom_factor * length * cos(angle)
y_new = zoom_factor * length * sin(angle)

x_new_topleft = x_new + x_center
y_new_topleft = y_new + y_center
```

Note that this assumes the number of pixels used for length and width stays the same after zooming. Note also that some rounding should take place (keep everything double precision, and only round to int *after* all calculations)

In the code above, `atan2` is the four-quadrant arctangent, available in most programming languages, and `hypot` is simply `sqrt(x*x + y*y)`, but then computed more carefully (e.g., to avoid overflow etc.), also available in most programing languages.

Is this indeed what you were after?

Comment: helpful, but not solving the issue for some reason..thanks for your time anyway.. as the above is very intersting and makes sense. There must be something here that I am overlooking somewhere.

Comment: What happens when you use this method? What errors do you see?

Comment: Difficult to explain, but here is something I found: At zoom factor 1, the left pupil is at 239,209 and at zoom factor 2, it is at 201,133. Does that help?

Comment: hmm what is the resolution of that image?

Comment: thank you for asking THAT question! It just struck me.. because the image is actually inside a container which is 550x500, but when you mentioned that above, I took a look at the image itself and it was 550x568.. when I resized the image to match the container, then all works well. Now the only problem is that users can upload their OWN photos and I cannot control the dimensions of that.. if I can determine the dimensions of the user's photo, can I somehow factor this into the equation?

Comment: Sure you can! The resolution (`image_width` and `image_height`) determines the values of `x_center` and `y_center`, as seen on the top 2 lines. So, for each photo, first extract those values, and then run them through the algorithm above

Comment: Working now. You are my hero, man... saved me there! thank you!